# Strange shell behaviour

Tags: shell

Here is a simple bash script:

```
a="asd"
b="qf"
echo "$a.$b"
echo "$a_$b"
```

It's output is:

```
asd.qf
qf
```

Why the second line is not "`asd_qf`" but "`qf`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you haven't defined a variable named `a_`. For that second printout to work, use:

```
echo "${a}_$b"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second `echo` displays the value of variable `$a_` which is unset.

Use `echo "${a}_$b"`

Answer (score 3):

The shell has rules about what can go in a variable name, and `$a_` is interpreted as the variable named `a_` (there is no variable with that name so its value is empty).

You can always add braces to be explicit.  In this case, `${a}_$b` will clearly identify what the variable name is and the result will be what you expect.